# Controls with the same physical size

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, resolution, dpi

I am making an application and trying to get my controls to be the same (physical, in cm, inches,...) size even showed when showed on different screens (using differnt resolutions, dpi). I tried scaling by DPI in winforms. It scales the controls to what it thinks to be the same size, but it is infact off.

What is the best way to get controls to be the same physical sizes on different screens in c#.
I prefer winforms but WPF is fine too.

Comment: I'd say use the [Panels Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel(v=vs.110).aspx) in combination with Docking in WinForms, and for WPF try reading through this tutorial: [wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties](http://wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html).

Comment: i'm looking for controls that are 1cm on one screen to be one 1cm on another screen aswell. Not a basic layout

Comment: Ok, I understand. I'd go with WPF then. The properties height & width should accept cm-based parameters I think. *EDIT*: see answer of +ArsenMkrt below.

Comment: To do what you're asking, Windows would need to know what size your monitor is, and it doesn't. There's no place in Control Panel where you can tell it whether you're using an ancient 15" CRT, a 27" LCD, a 60" high-def TV, or a projector (where the physical size depends on how far the projector is from the wall, another thing Windows can't possibly know). I've long thought their "DPI" terminology was terribly misleading, because it doesn't tie back to actual inches in any way. In some cases it might be a rough approximation, but that's all you get.

Comment: the rough approximation is what i'll have to work with, i just found that out myself. what i do now in WPF is get the system DPI and divide it by 96 (DIU) to get a factor. I enlarge my controls by this factor. For some reason i'm not gonna look into this does not work with winforms.

Comment: One easy approach would be to provide *calibration*, when you offer user to measure a *standard* (let's say, ask to measure dimension of the rectangle, which size you know in pixels). Then calculate a factor and size everything appropriately. In winforms it will be a pain, but `WPF` is designed with keeping that idea in mind, though I can't tell you the best approach of applying *factor* to dimensions in it.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF it is simple

```
<Window ... Height="10cm" Width="20cm"> </Window>
```

Comment: yes, this would be beautiful if it actually worked... somehow on one of my screens a button defined at 10cm is 11cm and on the other screen it's 6cm.

Comment: hmm, that is strange because MSDN says that the units are device independence device-independent units (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.height.aspx) I never measure honestly :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirements a while ago and the direction I decided to go is a combination of [C++ and C#/WPF](https://github.com/tgpdyk/WPF-Controls-using-physical-size).

Please feel free to send in any comment.